# props value as index in JSON file - React Hooks

Tags: json, react-hooks

I am making a developing in react hooks. So, there is a parent component which sends some props to a child one. The parent calls the child with this

```
<SelectLocation city={cityValue} />
```

I use 2 JSON files. This is city1.json

```
[{"value":"city1","towns":[{"value":"town1_1"},{"value":"town1_2"}]}]
```

and city2.json

```
[{"value":"city2","towns":[{"value":"town2_1"},{"value":"town2_2"}]}]
```

'cityValue' is a string and is the index to determine the value of the array of JSON's files used in the child. The child 'SelectLocation.js' is the following

```
import React, {useState,  useEffect} from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import City1 from './city1.json'
import City2 from './city2.json'


export default function SelectLocation(props) {

const allData ={City1,City2}
const [val, setVal] = useState('')
const [town,setTown] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    var cityChoose = props.city // Example: if props.city = "City1"
    console.log(cityChoose) //  "City1"
    var newData = allData[cityChoose] 
    console.log(newData) //  0:{"value":"city1","towns":[{"value":"town1_1"},{"value":"town1_2"}]}
    setTown(newData[0].towns) //error "can't read 'towns' from undefined "
  }, [])

return (
    <div className='row'>
     ...code to use the array "town"
    </div>
)
}
```

I don't know the reason of the error, because if I made this

```
...
var cityChoose = "City1"
var newData = allData[cityChoose] 
console.log(newData) //  0:{"value":"city1","towns":[{"value":"town1_1"},{"value":"town1_2"}]}
setTown(newData[0].towns) // Town=[{"value":"town1_1"},{"value":"town1_2"}]
...
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you try to use: `newData["0"]`

Comment: yes I did it, unfortunately the same result